# How to connect a HANA Server and a PostgreSQL Database Server?

Tags: postgresql, hana

I am a newbie in **HANA** and sorry if I have asked anything wrong. I want to connect **HANA** with **PostgreSQL** Server in order to access the data which is in PostgreSQL. I am not using HANA Studio and all the work is done in the command line.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have tried for sample data with converting the tables to csv files with **COPY schema_name.table_name TO '/path/table_name.csv'
WITH CSV QUOTE AS '"' ESCAPE AS '\';**  and then prepared the control file and imported the file .Since I have large amount of data I don't think this will be a good idea.That's why I am searching how to connect the two servers and then access the data.

Comment: as a comment: HDBSQL is not considered the intended tool for most activities with SAP HANA. Use SAP HANA Studio and/or the Web based tools instead.

Comment: Now I am using SAP HANA Studio But I am finding difficulty to how to connect and access the data in PostgreSQL.I am only having the HANA STUDIO and no SAP HANA Data Services ETL.So is there any options rather than importing CSV files?

Comment: You can try one way by retrieving data from postgreSQL and then insert it to HANA database.The below link [How to Insert In HANA] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818409/insert-array-in-hana-with-java/41993163#41993163) will help you how to insert the data and the retrieving part will be as usual connection to postgres and store in objects.But this will be definitely slower than the IMPORT but it will automated so that you do not have to export csv and create control file and then import it.