# Insert array in HANA with JAVA

Tags: java, hana

I am having an arraylist of objects and trying to insert the list into HANA. So my insert code looks like

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn
        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES"
                + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ARRAY("+"1,2,3"+")");

for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATION_MAX; i++) {
   
    stmt.setInt(1, listofdata.get(i).get_id());
    stmt.setInt(2, listofdata.get(i).get_name());
    stmt.setInt(3, listofdata.get(i).get_place());
    stmt.setInt(4, listofdata.get(i).get_year());
    stmt.setInt(5, listofdata.get(i).get_day());
    stmt.setInt(6, listofdata.get(i).get_rollno());
    stmt.setInt(7, listofdata.get(i).get_main_subject());
    stmt.setArray(8, listofdata.get(i).get_elective());

    stmt.addBatch();

}

stmt.executeBatch();
```

Here `listofdata.get(i).get_elective()` returns an integer array.

But this does not work. According to my program ARRAY function is called each time but why does not it inserting into HANA database. So after a while I understood that I have to convert JAVA Array into HANA Array. How can I convert a java Array to HANA Array.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41673091/1770155)

Comment: Now my question is how to convert a java array to an HANA Array?

Comment: This is an iteration of the discussion we had in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677436/is-it-possible-bulk-insert-in-hana . Please follow the SO links I posted there.

Comment: @Lars Br. It is clear that HANA does not supports Java Array type .So how do I convert a Java Array  type to HANA Type Array.Here in the `ARRAY(?)` I have to place the HANA array  type right.Can you give some clarifaction on this?

Comment: You will have to iterate over the array and construct an ARRAY (.., ... ,... ) function out if it's elements. And this has to be done explicitly for every single array you want to insert. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102034/import-array-type-into-hana/40378906#40378906 I gave an example of how this works in SQLScript (slightly different scenario, but you should get the gist of it).

Comment: @LarsBr. I am trying to understand your SQLScript but it does not give me a clear idea because I am not very good in SQLScript. So do you have the same in  any other programming languages like Java or anything else.It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Nope, I don't have that ready. What exactly is unclear now? For the insert statement your have to create a string that goes like INSERT INTO... (1, 'bla', 10-12-2016,... ARRAY( ....,...,...) ). That's all standard. Just fill the array function with each element of your java array.

Comment: @LarsBr.  
You mean like this INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,ARRAY(arr[1],arr[2],arr[3])) where arr is the array which stores the elements.But here only I have a problem that my array length is not fixed So I cannot keep like arr[1] to arr[3] since it differs for all the elements.

Comment: Correct, for each length of ARRAY you will need a separate INSERT statement.

Comment: @LarsBr. Yeah but I am struggling to implement that because I have the array `arr` So i know the length (say as k) then how to come with the statement `INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,ARRAY(arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],....arr[k]))`.Could you help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RKR ok, here you have your example:

```java
     /*
     * We're goin to insert several arrays into the HANA table, 
     * with different lengths
     * 
     * let's assume we already got a table like this
     * CREATE COLUMN TABLE T3 ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY, C1 INT ARRAY );
     */

    Integer[][] myarr ={ {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2}, {1,2,3} };

    String testSection = "Insert Arrays one by one";
    stopWatch.start(testSection);
    myDBconn.setAutoCommit(false);

    Statement stmt = myDBconn.createStatement();

    stmt = myDBconn.createStatement();

    stmt.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE DEVDUDE.T3");

    // loop over our array of arrays and visit each once
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (myarr.length); i++) {
        int curr_length = myarr[i].length;

        String arrayFunction = "ARRAY (";

        for (int j = 0; j < (curr_length); j++){

            arrayFunction = arrayFunction.concat(myarr[i][j].toString()) ;

            // add comma if this is not the last element
            if (j < (curr_length - 1)){
                arrayFunction = arrayFunction.concat(", ") ;
            }
        }

        arrayFunction = arrayFunction + ")" ;
        // now the arrayFunction should loook like this
        // ARRAY ( ..., .... ,... )

        String insCMD = "INSERT INTO T3 (id, c1) "
                        + " VALUES (" + i + ", " 
                        + arrayFunction 
                        + " ) ";

        System.out.println(insCMD);
        int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate(insCMD);

        System.out.println("Loop round " + i
                    + ", last affected row count " + affectedRows);
        }


    myDBconn.commit();
    stmt.close();
    stmt = null;
```

And no, this code does **not** sanitise the input to the INSERT statement but that has to be done in order to avoid SQL injection.

When I run the code this is what gets printed:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (id, c1)  VALUES (0, ARRAY (1) ) 
Loop round 0, last affected row count 1
INSERT INTO T3 (id, c1)  VALUES (1, ARRAY (1, 2) ) 
Loop round 1, last affected row count 1
INSERT INTO T3 (id, c1)  VALUES (2, ARRAY (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ) 
Loop round 2, last affected row count 1
INSERT INTO T3 (id, c1)  VALUES (3, ARRAY (1, 2) ) 
Loop round 3, last affected row count 1
INSERT INTO T3 (id, c1)  VALUES (4, ARRAY (1, 2, 3) ) 
Loop round 4, last affected row count 1
```

And a SELECT on the table returns:

```
ID  C1           
0   1            
1   1, 2         
2   1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3   1, 2         
4   1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Finally I too figured it out.Nearly same as yours but you did more formally where I converted the whole array to String by `Arrays.toString(arr)` and just concatenated with` ""+ +" "` .Indeed your method is more standard and will be useful for others too who were looking for the same solution.It is very kind of you to give clear explanation on the code

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard code but still works fine.Hope it helps anyone.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATION_MAX; i++) {

        String arraylist=Arrays.toString(listofdata.get(i).get_arraylist.replace("[","").replace("]",""));
        id=listofdata.get(i).get_id();
        name= listofdata.get(i).get_name();
        place=listofdata.get(i).get_place();
        year= listofdata.get(i).get_year();
        day=listofdata.get(i).get_day();
        rollno=   listofdata.get(i).get_rollno();
        main_subject= listofdata.get(i).get_main_subject();
        elective= listofdata.get(i).get_elective();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql="INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE values("+

           +name+","
            place+","
            year+day+","
            rollno+","
            main_subject+","
            elective"+","
            "ARRAY("+arraylist+")" ;


        stmt.addbatch(sql);
    }
    stmt.executeBatch();
    stmt.close();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();
```

Comment: @Lars Br. The above code works fine for me but it takes nearly 1 hour to load only 1 million rows (even in batch insert) which I find not quite impresive.Can this be solved?